# Read Byte from BluetoothGatt

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

Does anyone know how to print/read/get the value of a Byte stored in a BluetoothGattCharacteristic?  I am receiving data from a BT Sensor and need to figure out what the correct read format should be:  ex.  SINT8, UINT8, FLOAT.

I am hoping that once I get that byte value, that will clue me into the equation needed to convert that value to a usable unit of measure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try BluetoothGattCharacteristic.getDescriptor() for UUID 0x2904, i.e Characteristic Format.

This descriptor value, if present,  will describe the format of the BluetoothGattCharacteristic value.

See https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/descriptors/Pages/DescriptorViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.characteristic_presentation_format.xml

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the set of bytes is just going to be quite literally just that. It is dependent on how the client device decides to write the data onto the characteristic. The one thing that should probably be taken into account is if its little endian or big endian, because any convertor that you use in Android would be big-endian I believe.

Comment: I am positive that this also helps.  Thank you very much.